# AR Object Relative to Device Location using Wikitude SDK

Tags: javascript, android, augmented-reality, wikitude, android-augmented-reality

i am working with an android AR application.I am using Wikitude SDK for implementing augmented reality.

I have developed a augmented reality app.Now i need to place AR Object always in front of the Device.

I have used AR.RelativeLocation to place the AR Object relative to user location.But it always shows north  to user location.

```
 var markerLocation =new AR.RelativeLocation(null,50 ,0, 0);
```

My requirement is to place the Object directly in front of the device camera.
Please suggest the appropriate way to implement this.Can i implement this by changing the AR.RelativeLocation parameters.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

AR.RelativeLocation allows you to place objects around the user but not directly "on top of the camera".
SnapToScreen feature is related to your query but only works for 2D tracking, compare video snapToScreen sample.

Your feature is therefore not supported for Geo-AR, but you may define a div in html to display content on top of the camera-layer, compare POI samples.

Best regards

Comment: Is there any way to drag the placed AR Object to another location like in IKEA Catalog App ?

Comment: Current SDK (December 2016) does not offer this feature. Stay tuned:
www.wikitude.com/download